# App gets shrinked on Android 3.0 tablet

Tags: java, android, xml, screen, shrink

As seen here [image: this picture] my app gets shrinked on Samsung Galaxy Tab with Android 3.0

It is also shrinked in emulator, but at graphical layout it looks ok. main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<WebView android:id="@+id/web_engine"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is OK on phone screens.

Comment: Could you post your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely not including xLargeScreens in the Manifest:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Hope that is it/and helps.

```
 <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Should help.

Comment: That is it. Thanks. This is my first Android app :)

Comment: Awesome. That's my first answer on Stack, and I was right! Happy to help =) EDIT: Congrats on your first app!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your app is run in some kind of [Screen Compatibility Mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html). Follow the link and read up on what conditions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` might cause your app to enter this state.

Answer (score 1):

Your android XML look fine and unless you have a different layout resource for large/xlarge screens it is hard to see how this could be a problem.

Consider the possibility that the issue is not in the android XML but in the displayed HTML/CSS? That is that you are seeing a large webview on the screen with only a small display of HTML filling it.